# How to check the merges between branch and trunk in SVN?

Tags: svn, merge, branch, trunk

I have committed many changes in branch , after merged to trunk.

So I have done many commit, merge, commit operations.
Now I am not sure that all was made correct.
Can I check if I not missed merge some revisions to trunk?

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.7.1, and could switch for that comparison to svn command client (but only if not possible with TortoiseSVN).

Comment: Depending on the version and tool you are using (<= 1.4 or >= 1.5; svn command line or TortoiseSVN) the answer will be different. With SVN 1.5 the feature merge tracking was implemented, have a look at [merge tracking](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging) and the [mergeinfo property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo).

Comment: better Tortois, but if this is not possible with Tortoise also in command line

Comment: And which version do you use?

Comment: Have you merged only revisions (cherry pick) to the trunk or did you merge the whole branch to trunk (multiple times)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Subversion 1.5.x merge tracking is implemented. So every time you do a merge in Subversion, the info about the merge you have done is automatically tracked in Subversion in the directory where you started the merging. If you do that all the time e.g. from the trunk, all the mergeinfo will be combined there.

Have a look at the documentation of [TortoiseSVN 1.7](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#tsvn-dug-showlog-mergetrack), and try to open the same dialog in TortoiseSVN. When using the checkbox "Include merged revisions", you will see not only the revisions from the current trunk, but also from the branches. The same information condensed you will see when you open the properties dialog for that directory:

[image]

The screenshot shows the merge tracking info (or short mergeinfo), so you see I have merged revisions 4-6 from b1 and 12 from b2 (whatever that means).

You will find a similar documentation to the [SVN command client here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.mergeinfo).

Answer (score 1):

Start the "Merge" dialogue as if you were to port further changes. When prompted for a revision range, hit "Show log". Revisions that have already been merged will be greyed out and won't be eligible.